# Waiting for TimePickerFragment to return time

Tags: java, android, timepicker

New to JAVA and Android coding and trying my first practical project.

I don't understand how to make processing wait until timekeeperdialog returns a value.

In my Main Activity I have created getters and setters to variables (first time doing this btw):

```
    private int pickhour;
    private int pickminute;

    public MainActivity(){

        pickhour = 0;
        pickminute = 0;


    }



    public void setpickhour(int pickhour) {
        this.pickhour = pickhour;

    }

    public int getpickhour(){
        return this.pickhour;
    }

    public void setpickminute(int pickminute) {
        this.pickminute = pickminute;

    }

    public int getPickminute(int pickminute) {
        return this.pickminute;

    }
```

I call the dialog box with this, and then expecting processing to pause until the TimePicker returns a value, I have a Toast to show results. The Toast fires as soon as the Timepicker appears.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"TimePicker");

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time Picker" + String.valueOf(pickhour) + ":" + String.valueOf(pickminute), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And my fragment looks like this :

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

private MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

//onTimeSet() callback method
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
    //Do something with the user chosen time
    //Get reference of host activity (XML Layout File) TextView widget

    ma.setpickhour(hourOfDay);
    ma.setpickminute(minute);





}

}
```

I tried looping through a boolean set by the  ontimeset method to force waiting on a return value, but my application just hung.

What fundamental concept am I missing? I'm on vacation, so spent a day & a half trying to figure this out.

Comment: what sort of processing,  are  the processing ran by threads?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that; I'm that new at this.

As soon as the app executes the line : DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

The timepicker appears, and the Toast fires.

Comment: I was sort of expecting to be able to write a method like :

timeChosen = askUserToPickTime();

but now understand that isn't how this works.  

I am a VBA hobbyist programmer struggling to learn java & android programming.

Comment: You're not the only one to stumble into this trap - I can remember my first login dialog :) You have to use some type of Listener with the Dialog to get the result from the user actions. Maybe this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#ShowingADialog) on Dialogs is helpful. There is also a special chapter on [TimePicker dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers#TimePicker)

Comment: I might be getting a handle on this. Instead of TimePickerDialog returning the values back to my MainActivity class, I call the methods I need to perform after a time is picked, from the TimePickerFragment class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

private MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
//Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

//Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,
        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

//onTimeSet() callback method
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){
//Do something with the user chosen time
//Get reference of host activity (XML Layout File) TextView widget

ma.setpickhour(hourOfDay);
ma.setpickminute(minute);



Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time Picker" + String.valueOf(pickhour) + ":" + String.valueOf(pickminute), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

And if you are only using fragment for timePicker there is no need of the fragment.

In this case you can try this in MainActivity -

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

 TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    setpickhour(hourOfDay);
                    setpickminute(minute);
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Time Picker");
            mTimePicker.show();
```

Does your code work? Because you cannot pass "this" as second argument in TimePickerDialog constructor.

Comment: >>Does your code work? Because you cannot pass "this" as second argument in TimePickerDialog 

yes it does.


>>And if you are only using fragment for timePicker there is no need of the fragment.

When I first created a TimePicker (not dialog), I wasn't getting the OK, Cancel button. 
I discovered sample code with TimePickerDialog in it that did give me OK/Cancel, but it was setup as a fragment.  
Your comment that it didn't have to be in a fragment lead me to a new example, where I have it running just fine in a test app's MainActivity.

Comment: In the OnTimeSet method of my new code, I can get the set value. I need to figure out how detect the Cancel button.

I can't figure out how to get the Clock format with AM/PM. The one that comes up is the clock with 24 hour choice.  I have tried a variety of Themes.

The code I found is at https://pastebin.com/AANbnzHb  I'm getting closer. Thank you all.